# Error: PackageApplication failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode4.1

Here is the full error:

```
PackageApplication failed with exit code 1.
Packaging application: '/Users/jacensherman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-01-15/ROCK CCYM 1-15-12 12.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ROCK CCYM.app'
Arguments: embed=/Users/jacensherman/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/DE189CD6-2959-4099-BF20-728294DDC890.mobileprovision  verbose=1  output=/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/45319059-F51E-4E9E-9673-A96755E6E5EE-7820-000012E82A2B8CDD/app.ipa  sign=iPhone Distribution: Laura Hungerford  
Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/jacensherman
LOGNAME = jacensherman
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0:0
DISPLAY = /tmp/launch-Op8ypA/org.x:0
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
PATH = /Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SHELL = /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-4CajrF/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /tmp/launch-IILFBQ/Render
TMPDIR = /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/
USER = jacensherman
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.12

Output directory: '/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/45319059-F51E-4E9E-9673-A96755E6E5EE-7820-000012E82A2B8CDD/app.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp /Users/jacensherman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-01-15/ROCK CCYM 1-15-12 12.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ROCK CCYM.app /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/jacensherman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-01-15/ROCK CCYM 1-15-12 12.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ROCK CCYM.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/Users/jacensherman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-01-15/ROCK CCYM 1-15-12 12.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ROCK CCYM.app: valid on disk
/Users/jacensherman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-01-15/ROCK CCYM 1-15-12 12.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ROCK CCYM.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
]
Done checking the original app
### Embedding '/Users/jacensherman/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/DE189CD6-2959-4099-BF20-728294DDC890.mobileprovision'
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
+ /bin/cp -rp /Users/jacensherman/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/DE189CD6-2959-4099-BF20-728294DDC890.mobileprovision /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/entitlements_rawWi8KYOYq /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [Executable=/private/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app/ROCK CCYM
]
+ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Set :get-task-allow NO /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/entitlements_plistlodEHngf
Program /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/plutil -lint /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/entitlements_plistlodEHngf
Program /usr/bin/plutil returned 0 : [/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/entitlements_plistlodEHngf: OK
]
### Codesigning '/Users/jacensherman/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/DE189CD6-2959-4099-BF20-728294DDC890.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Distribution: Laura Hungerford'
+ /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Distribution: Laura Hungerford --resource-rules=/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/entitlements_plistlodEHngf /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app: replacing existing signature
]
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv -R=anchor apple generic and (certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)) /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 3 : [/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app: valid on disk
/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
]
error: Codesign check fails : /var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app: valid on disk
/var/folders/b7/h7p31ljx7nlfxbyg30mbr5xh0000gn/T/PV4Pz7025E/Payload/ROCK CCYM.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
```

I have all the certificates I am supposed to and the target code signs match the project code signs.

I have looked at others with similar answers, but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865250/codesign-check-fails-xcode-4

Comment: Can you codesign your app in terminal ? using codesign utility: codesign -f -s {SIGNER-IDENTITY} "/Path for your .app file" and see if it works.

Comment: same issue for me and other guys... check on apple dev forum! It could be an apple technical problem with certificates...

Comment: I'm going to call apple tomorrow to see whats going on and i'll post whatever I find out.

Comment: ZSorry guys, they had no useful info. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing:

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin
```